# How do I access hidden files in Finder with Applescript?

Tags: applescript

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ON
```

Now it works

```
tell application "Finder" to get folder ".spring" of home
#folder ".spring" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder"
```

...

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles OFF
```

Now it doesn't

```
tell application "Finder" to get folder ".spring" of home
#Can’t get folder ".spring" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk  of application "Finder"
```

I need to copy a file to that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid the Finder in this case if possible.  `do shell script` should be able to do what you want.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fileToMove to choose file
    set targetPath to "~/.spring"
    set moveCmd to "mv '" & (POSIX path of fileToMove) & "' " & targetPath
    do shell script moveCmd
end tell
```

Comment: Using bash is ugly, but I suppose it works. I hoped you could do a trick like "tell finder to get hidden file" or something with system events.

Comment: indeed it is, but I find that oftentimes with Applescript it is the most reliable way to do it.  In this case, the Finder is explicitly prohibited form seeing invisible files (via that hidden `defaults` setting) so it seems that its inability to access the folder is what the API designers intended.